okhttp post form data return 200 post failed without error
okhttp api, using ok3, have followed this official doc from square, https://square.github.io/okhttp/,
post form data response return always 200 but didn't happen
code here, anyone can give some pointers
 var mediatype = "application/json".toMediaType()

                 var body = Gson().toJson(note).toRequestBody(mediatype)
                val request = Request.Builder()
                 .url(url).post(body)
                 .build()

                var resp = client.newCall(request).execute()

